# How to update selected row in Gridview?

Tags: c#, sql-update

I have a TextBox with id=txtPlace and a gridview. If a user selects a row an put some Information in the TextBox and click on save. The Information should replace older records in the database(SQL)

```html
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var id = GridView2.SelectedDataKey.Values[0].ToString();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {

            string query = "UPDATE user SET place= @place where ID = @ID ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place", txtPlace.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

        }
    }
```

But It does not work. When I click on save, nothing happens.

Comment: You don't open the connection and you don't call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: see example running SqlCommand: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

Comment: In addition to the things stated above you also need to reload the table data/Datasource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a couple crucial steps - opening the `SqlConnection` and executing the `SqlCommand`.  Since this is something where you don't expect a result back, you can just use `ExecuteNonQuery()`.  You probably should wrap `SqlCommand` in a `using` block as well, since it's `IDisposable`, and your variable is incorrectly named.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var id = GridView2.SelectedDataKey.Values[0].ToString();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        conn.Open(); // actually connect to the server
        string query = "UPDATE user SET place= @place where ID = @ID "; // change @D to @ID
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place", txtPlace.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // actually execute your statement
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "UPDATE user SET place= @place where ID = @D ";
```

I guess that you've put the wrong variable name, look @D is different of @ID